# Powershell Script to create and send new Teams Live Event

Tags: powershell, outlook, microsoft-teams

I need to create and send an **invitation** for a Teams Live Event. I just found scripts for Meeting and not for Live Event.
The main idea of this invitation is that the recipient can accept or not in the mail and that the event is added to their calendar.
Thanks for your help !

Comment: At the moment there is no power shell cmdlet for creating live event.If you want this feature to be added in future please raise a [uservoice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public-preview/category/182881-developer-platform)

Answer (score 1):

As of (2/2/2021) there is no power shell cmdlet for creating live event. If you want this feature to be added in future please raise a [uservoice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public-preview/category/182881-developer-platform)